# Reference sample for ClaimsAuthorizationManager in Windows Identity Foundation 4.5

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity, adfs2.0, azman

Sorry for the long question, trying to get all my points across!

I have been spending a considerable amount of time researching how to update our existing Identity and Access Management scheme to a more modern platform that solves a number of business and compliance requirements we have especially from ISO27001 perspective.

I have two primary goals to achieve:
1) Be able to report on what business operations/tasks can a user perform?
2) Be able to monitor in real time or through historical reports what a user is doing/has done?

We currently use a mixture of custom authentication and authorisation (using SQL back end for both) and AD Domain services for Authentication and AD group membership / role demand for authorisation.

I propose we use AD Domain Services for Authentication across all our software but from a claims based perspective with ADFS 2.0 as our STS server. We can then start leveraging claims within our applications and for those using role demands, they will still continue to work.

I am pretty happy with all of the above however we want to use a more granular entitlement management / authorisation scheme and therefore I want to use a ClaimsAuthorizationManager for the decision and enforcement point.

Problem is that WIF does not implement a concrete version, the developer is left entirely to their own choices with no guidance. I cannot find a single example of anything approaching something fit for business.

I am therefore looking for any advice on how to architect a enterprise class authorisation scheme that works in a similar way to AzMan or NetSqlAzMan. I suggest a generic simple ClaimsAuthorizationManager class that each application can use. This class calls into a shared WCF service which in turn uses a SQL back end to store business operations/tasks and the entitlements users have on these. The user objects woudl be synced from AD so that AD is providing authentication, claims and my custom system is providing authorisation rules. This service being centralised and singular helps with my first goal.

This system would log each request which will help with the second of my initial goals.

Any advice, examples or help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are right - since AuthZ is so application specific - Microsoft did not provide any concrete implementations.

You already seem to have very specific ideas how that should work. Why don't you build such a sample and open source it - so you can gather feedback and maybe improve it based on that?

Comment: Thanks for replying Dominic. Whilst I will most likely go ahead and do this I was hoping for some guidance on the architecture of such a system and the data schema in particular. I guess I keep asking/looking since I just cannot believe there are no references for this. It feels like I am the only person asking about it! There is just so little information on the subject and I can't help feeling that I am missing something fundamental!

Comment: I really think that many people have written something similar to this. but for internal use. A public reference implementation would be nice. Let me know when you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts.

Roles are a well-understood pattern e.g. [Universal Data Models](http://www.univdata.com/AboutUs/UniversalDataModelsLLCOverview/tabid/246/Default.aspx).

ADFS can pass groups as roles - [ADFS : Sending groups as claims](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2012/06/adfs-sending-groups-as-claims.html). You can then use the IsInRole or location tag. This may be too simplistic for you?

ADFS can log Success or Failure Audits - "Federation Service Properties" - Events.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to move us away from the roles based access control to ensure that applications are decoupled from knowledge of the group/role membership. If we rely on applications to understand the membership of a role then changing this requires changes to the application code and there is no centralised place to report on or control what a user can do. I think one of the advantages of WIF and the ClaimsAuthorizationManager is the abstraction it provides and the ability to centralise the policy decision point for your IAM. I just wish there was a reference architecture somewhere!